# Integration of django-oscar and django-cms

Tags: django, django-cms, django-oscar

I want to build a django oscar ecommerce web app.
A Required fearure in this app is a content management system, therefore I want to integrate django-cms in my app. After some research I found apphooks but there is no guide on google for integration of django-oscar and django-cms.
Can anyone tell me the way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still looking for this solution, but i created a content management system by combining Django-CMS and Oscar Commerce with tons of additional features including user messasaging, docker support, graphql, support for several payment providers and more.

https://github.com/bastianhilton/alternate-cms

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of integration you want to do, you should check [Wagtail](https://wagtail.io/) which is another Django CMS, well documented, the community seems to be growing up.

Adding Wagtail to an existing project is explained [here](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html) and works well with a django-oscar project.